# Assign 0 to Nan, NA and Inf

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `group()` and `summarise()` functions. And cant work out how to either exclude the Not Sized row OR make all results for Not Sized appear as, 0?

The categorical variable I am using (`Size`) has 4 categories:
Small, Medium, Large and Not sized.

If Not Sized, there is no data in the `Total_Managers` or `Total Employees` columns.

I have tried to assign `na.rm = TRUE`, but it provides "NaN", "NA" and "Inf" results, if I take away `na.rm = TRUE` and try `na.omit = TRUE`, or use both, all rows (Large, Medium, Small and Not Sized) comes back as NA results for each column.

```
dataframe %>% group_by(Size) 
%>% summarise
(Mean_Managers = mean(Total_Managers, na.rm = TRUE), 
Median_Managers = median(Total_Managers, na.rm = TRUE), 
Max_Employeess = max(Total_Employees, na.rm = TRUE))
```

| Size | Mean_Managers | Median_Managers | Max_Employees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Large | 9 | 3 | 15 |
| Medium | 7 | 3 | 8 |
| Not Sized | NaN | NA | Inf |
| Small | 5 | 5 | 2 |

So again, any tips on how to either exclude the Not Sized row OR make all results for Not Sized appear as, 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included at the start and it removed the `NaN`, `NA`, `Inf` results/Not Sized column before starting the group and

```r
dataframe <− na.omit(dataframe)

dataframe %>% 
  group_by(Size) %>% 
  summarise(Mean_Managers = mean(Total_Managers, na.rm = TRUE),
            Median_Managers = median(Total_Managers, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Max_Employeess = max(Total_Employees, na.rm = TRUE))
```